# Вытащить из URL значение code параметра в query используя регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, python-3.x, url

Помогите вытащить из URL значение code

```
import re

url = https://xxx.omsk.ru/?code=884gdczv72ka3kkco6sxoen2ugp380y1&state=&domain=xxx.omsk.ru

code = re.findall(r'code=\w+', r.url)
print(code)
```

я получаю вывод print code=884gdczv72ka3kkco6sxoen2ugp380y1
мне бы вывести без 'code=', одно значение

Comment: спасибо, но я просто отнял пять первых символов от строки code[5:] но вариант со специальным парсером хорош, позже перепишу на нем)))

Answer (score 3):

Используйте готовые классы и методы, доступные в модуле [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html):

```
import urlparse
url = 'https://xxx.omsk.ru/?code=884gdczv72ka3kkco6sxoen2ugp380y1&state=&domain=xxx.omsk.ru'
parsed = urlparse.urlparse(url)
print(urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)['code'])
```

[См. демо](https://ideone.com/uRG3s8)

В ознакомительных целях добавлю пример регулярного выражения, которое часто используется в JavaScript:

```
[&?]code=([^&]+)
```

[Демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/mJffcV/1)

- `[&?]` - 1 символ, либо `?`, либо `&` (`[...]` — это *символьный класс*, который используется для поиска диапазонов символов или же отдельных, конкретных символов)
- `code=` - последовательность символов (т.е. подстроку) `code=`
- `([^&]+)` - Захватывающая группа №1, находит 1 и более символов, отличных от `&` (тут `[^...]` — это *исключающий символьный класс*, с помощью которого осуществляется поиск любых символов, отличных от определённых в классе).

[Демо в Python](https://ideone.com/8uiAsu):

```
import re
url = 'https://xxx.omsk.ru/?code=884gdczv72ka3kkco6sxoen2ugp380y1&state=&domain=xxx.omsk.ru'
m = re.search(r'[&?]code=([^&]+)', url)
if m:
    print(m.group(1))
```

Comment: Можно ещё unquote() добавить. И поправить импорты для Питона 3.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант это использовать substr и не переписывать регулярное выражение:

```
code[5:]
```

Прочитать про него и посмотреть примеры можно по [ссылке](https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring-python)